# Heading/text is breaking when screen size gets smaller

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've noticed some of the headings and text on my site breaks when the screen width gets smaller. Here is an example: https://gyazo.com/c1833d69ff3a2b976bff8f497e4f20c2

You can really notice it on the 'g' in heading, and most of the body text. I've tried a lot of different things with CSS but not sure what is causing it.

Also, I can't replicate the issue on Firefox so it maybe be something with Chrome. My Chrome is updated.

Comment: I can't see it breaking on the gif...maybe show some more material where it is standing out more.

Comment: For people to better help you and to make this question more relevant for future users please add the code that is in question instead of just a link to your website. You can [read about how to ask a question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @oelhajoui Look at the 'g' in heading, and the first line of the text, 'consectetur...'

Comment: @crazymatt Thanks. the only issue is if I just copy paste the code into jsfiddle or codepen, the issue isnt there. its something on my site, maybe the wordpres theme.

Comment: This seems like a rendering isseue (just for your computer). Give the link and we will check it out.

Comment: Can you post an image of the part that is breaking?

Comment: @oelhajoui http://jdcpreviews.com/pc/home-computers/h5-home-pc/ 

It seems to be the arrow animation under the  "View PC Models" button that is causing the issue. I removed it on this page: http://jdcpreviews.com/pc/home-computers/h5-home-pc-2/

The issue occurs when the screen size in under 800px.